# how to implement signature with user made in Node JS

Tags: node.js, angular, express, digital-signature

How to implement signature with user made, similarly when Amazon delivery person comes up to deliver and they asked to sign to their mobile with Node JS?

Any reference is appreciated.

I'm using Angular frontend and NodeJS backend.

What is the name of this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a ready made library like [this one (demo)](http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/) for a Digital signature solution [in this link](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad), which uses HTML5 canvas (looks maintained, never used it myself though).